# JQMobile 1.1.0 App crashing on WebWorks

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am tryin to write an app for BB using webworks,phonegap and jquery mobile 1.1.0. I am trying to run the phonegap(cordova) 1.7 BB sample .
The sample runs properly if i leave it exactly the way it is from phonegap, but immediately i add any refrence to the jquery mobile libraries, the app doesnt go past the splash screen.

i have tried using Jquery mobile 1.0.1, and i still get the same results

Can anyone please tell me whats going on and what i can do to get Jquery mobile to work?

Comment: Post more code, I`ve made webworks/phonegap apps using jQuery mobile and haven't encountered that problem.

Comment: Can you give me a link to an example so i can try it out? The only code i added is the script tag for the Jquery and Jquery mobile, i havent even added any code

Comment: I think i have partially solved the problem,it was the jqmobile css file that was missing. but now though the code runs well in ripple emulator ,it doesnt work on the phone emulator,it still keeps hanging at the splashscreen

Comment: Post the code and I will try to help.

Comment: What BlackBerry OS are you targetting (BBOS, Playbook OS, BlackBerry 10) ?
What version of cordova are you using ? (Sounds like 1.7)
What are you using to test ? (Sounds like Ripple and an emulator)